# como puedo mostrar un alert y que me cargue la pagina correctamente JSP y sweetalert2

Tags: ajax, web, alert

Cordial saludo

Buenos dias

tengo una pregunta estoy terminando un sistema con JSP y servlet pero como es la primera vez que uso servlet me esta dando problema cuando actualizo un registro el registro se actualiza pero en vez de redirigirme normal a la pagina me carga la pagina pero no me aplica carga la pagina correctamente

el codigo usado en servlet es el siguiente de editar usuario

```
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        Connection con =null;
        Conexion cn = new Conexion();
        PreparedStatement st = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
          String identificacion = request.getParameter("identificacion");
        String nombres = request.getParameter("nombresApellidos");
        String mail = request.getParameter("mail");
        String telefono = request.getParameter("telefono");
        String tipo = request.getParameter("tipo");
        String modalidad = request.getParameter("nombreModalidad");
        String semestre = request.getParameter("semestre");
        String id_campus = request.getParameter("idcampus");
        String id_facultad = request.getParameter("idfacultad");
        String id_programa = request.getParameter("idprograma");
        
        String editar = request.getParameter("btnModificarUsuario");
        String borrar = request.getParameter("btnEliminarUsuario");
        String uno="1";
        String dos="2";
        
        if(uno.equals(editar)){            
            try {
                String consultax = "UPDATE usuarios SET Name_users='" + nombres + "', Mail_users='" + mail + "', Phone_users='" + telefono + "', Type_users='" + tipo + "', Id_campus='" + id_campus + "', Id_faculty='" + id_facultad + "', Id_program='" + id_programa + "', Semestre='" + semestre + "', Modalidad='" + modalidad + "' WHERE Id_usuarios='" + identificacion + "'";
                con=cn.getConexion();
                st=(PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(consultax);
                st.executeUpdate();
                 out.println("<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js' ></script>");
                 out.println("<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@9'></script>");
                 out.println("<script>");
                 out.println("$(document).ready(function(){");
                 
                 out.println("Swal.fire(position:'center',"
                         + "icon:'success',"
                         + "title:'Se ha Actualizado los datos',timer:1500"
                         + "');");
                 out.println("})");
                 out.println("</script>");
                 //response.sendRedirect("administrador/ModificarUsuarios.jsp");
                //RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("ModificarUsuarios.jsp");
                //rd.include(request, response);
                
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                    out.print("Error 3: " + e);
            } finally {
                    try {
                        if (st != null) {
                            st.close();
                        }
                    } catch (SQLException e) {
                        out.print("Error 4: " + e);
                    }
            }  
        }
```

se recarga la pagina es cuando muestra el mensaje de registro en la pagina pero cuando acepto el la confirmacion de actualizado de datos en alert la  pagina es como si no fuera la pagina ya que si doy index me deberia de llevar al dashboard pero cuando doy click en inicio me lleva es al login.

me guie del presente ejemplo pero no si algo estara mal en mi codigo
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-FnjW4QKueQ&t=314s
[image: este es el error que me manda]

Comment: Hola Formatea el codigo del ejemplo que esta cortado.

Comment: cuando realizo la actualizacion de los datos me actualiza la tabla y me muestra el mensaje pero en la pagina no me carga los elementos de esta y no es la pagina correspondiente no se si lo estoy cargando bien o estoy cargando el sweetalert2 muy pronto

Comment: No es necesario que dupliques preguntas, pudiste haber editado la otra pregunta en la que te comente lo del SweetAlert, dicho esto, tu problema es un poco confuso, ¿la página se recarga y tu no quieres eso o al contrario, quieres que se recargue y no lo hace?

Comment: exacto solo que se muestre el alert despues de haber realizado los cambios en la pagina pero como soy nuevo estoy terminando este proyecto pero me hace falta esta pequeña parte la cual no sale ya que cuando actualizo los datos se recarga la pagina y muestra el alert en la pagina pero se recarga la pagina